# Can't seem to get a certain value to pass to another controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

So I have 3 controllers, let's say `ChatVC`, `MenuVC`, and `InviteVC`.

Starting on `ChatVC`, I open the menu and tap a button that dismisses the menu back to `ChatVC`, then segues to `InviteVC`.

Both `ChatVC` and `MenuVC` have the value I need to pass to `InviteVC` (`currentRoomID`). However it seems to be quite the issue getting that to `InviteVC`. `currentRoomID` is initialized on InviteVC as an empty string.

This is the action that is performed when I tap the button in the menu to take me to `InviteVC`:

```
@IBAction func invitePressed(_ sender: Any) {
    weak var pvc = self.presentingViewController
    self.dismiss(animated: true) {
        pvc?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "chatInvite", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

I've tried adding this in the dismiss closure, as well as in `viewDidLoad` of both `MenuVC` and `ChatVC`:

```
let inviteVC = InviteVipViewController()
inviteVC.currentRoomId = self.currentRoomID
```

I've tried passing it in `ChatVC`s prepareForSegue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? MenuViewController {
        destinationViewController.transitioningDelegate = self
        destinationViewController.interactor = interactor
        destinationViewController.currentRoomID = self.currentRoomID
    } else if segue.identifier == "chatInvite" {
        let inviteVC = InviteVipViewController()
        inviteVC.currentRoomID = self.currentRoomID
    }
}
```

And every time, `currentUserID` remains an empty string when I get to `InviteVC`. It didn't seem to be a problem when I was segueing to `InviteVC` straight from `MenuVC`, but since I changed it to the current transition (menu drops away back to `ChatVC`, then segues to `InviteVC`), it's seeming to be impossible to get that value passed.

This is incredibly frustrating so if anyone can help me try something I haven't tried before it will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Why do you handle the two possible segues so differently?

Comment: How do you mean? The reason the segue from Menu -> Invite is done that way (dismiss menu, then segue from Chat - > Invite), is that when I press "done" on the Invite VC and dismiss it, it goes right back to the chat - instead of going back to the slide out menu, then having to slide the menu back to get back to the chat,

Comment: I mean your prepare method. The first if you check the destination controller's type and then use the destination controller. The second you check segue id and then create a new instance. That's two completely different types of checks and two completely different ways of accessing/creating the destination view controller.

Comment: I didn't realize `let inviteVC = InviteVipViewController()` was creating a new view controller, I thought it was basically the same thing as `destinationViewController = segue.destination as? MenuViewController`. Made that fix though, and `currentRoomID` is still not getting passed correctly - it's still an empty string in Invite VC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have problem in prepareForSegue

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? MenuViewController {
    destinationViewController.transitioningDelegate = self
    destinationViewController.interactor = interactor
    destinationViewController.currentRoomID = self.currentRoomID
  // if identifier equals to chatInvite then you get your InviteViewController from segues Destination not by creating one
 } else if segue.identifier == "chatInvite" {
    let inviteVC = segue.destination as? InviteVipViewController
    inviteVC.currentRoomID = self.currentRoomID
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** What I can see your trying to segue from a ViewController which you have already dismissed. So I think you have to move that logic to your MainViewController in your case I assume it's **MenuViewController**

also you should not instantiate your InviteVIPViewController like this

```
let inviteVC = InviteVipViewController()
inviteVC.currentRoomId = self.currentRoomID
```

segue will do it for you

You can pass your currentRoomID using UserDefaults as well like

```
@IBAction func invitePressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    userDefaults.set(currentRoomID, forKey: "roomID")
    // call the synchronise so it sync force the user defaults to save
    userDefaults.synchronize()

weak var pvc = self.presentingViewController
self.dismiss(animated: true) {
    pvc?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "chatInvite", sender: nil)
  }
}
```

Now access your currentRoomID in inviteViewController viewDidLoad() 
also I assume the roomID as an int

```
 let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
 currentRoomID = userDefaults.integer(forKey: "roomID")
 // if string then you can use object and cast it to string like this
 currentRoomID = userDefaults.object(forKey: "roomID") as! String
```

Comment: Tried this, `currentRoomID` is still an empty string in `InviteVC`

Comment: if you read my note your trying to trigger the segue from a totally wrong viewController and that's why you can not send anything. try to fix that

Comment: I don't know any other way to handle the segue to get what I want - I need to tap the button in menu, have the menu dismiss itself back to the chat controller, THEN segue to the invite controller.

Comment: yes if you look at your code you're dismissing the menu and in completion your calling performSegue like so which means close this current ViewController  `self.dismiss(animated: true) {
        pvc?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "chatInvite", sender: nil)
    }`

Comment: Exactly. The segues work perfectly how they are now - I open the slide out menu, tap on "Invite", then the menu closes back to the chat and `InviteVC` is presented. The, when I press "done" on the invite VC, it dismisses itself back to the chat. But the room ID is not getting passed when we go to invite.

Comment: you have to add your `prepareForSegue()` in **chat** because it's **chatViewController** which is performing the segue that's why on dismiss you from invite. you returns to **chat** hope it's clear now

Comment: `prepareForSegue()` is indeed in chat view controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142358/discussion-between-khalid-afridi-and-kingtim).

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
let inviteVC = InviteVipViewController()
```

creates a completely new instance of the InviteVipViewController, completely unrelated to the instance to which you are about to segue.  You should instead use `segue.destination` (which IS the instance you are about to segue to).  The only proviso is that you should test to confirm that the destination is of the correct type (as you do for the segue to `MenuViewController`):

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? MenuViewController {
        destinationViewController.transitioningDelegate = self
        destinationViewController.interactor = interactor
        destinationViewController.currentRoomID = self.currentRoomID
    } else if segue.identifier == "chatInvite" {
        if let inviteVC = segue.destination as? InviteVipViewController {
            inviteVC.currentRoomID = self.currentRoomID
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the same approach as the other answer, I fixed it and tried the solution but currentRoomID is still an empty string in InviteVC.

Comment: I would do it differently if I could keep the segues working the same, but if I simply segue to invite VC from the menu, then when I hit "done" and call dismiss on that controller, it will go back to the menu - I need to to just go back to the chat when "done" is pressed

Answer (score -1):

I used to use segues and found them unnecessarily complicated. Here's a workaround...

In the part of your code where you import UIKit (at the top), add a variable for whatever you want to pass, in this case, let's say I want to pass a score.

```
//view controller one
import UIKit
var score = 25
```

Then  go in the view controller where you want to receive the-in this case score, and you can easily access it like it's a variable in your own view controller.

```
//Viewcontrollertwo
super.viewDidLoad()
score += 2
//score is now = 27, requires no segue
```

Comment: not sure why this was downgraded considering it works and I now use this instead of segues...